# Complex Lookup Function in Excel using 4 different lookup parameters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I am working on a project within an excel database and am trying to match 4 different properties which all have their own columns (A,B,C,D) to find a corresponding value on a different page (Sheet2!).  One sheet 2 the values are once again found in their own columns (B,C,D,E) and if all of the values match I then want the value in column A Sheet2! to be displayed in column E on sheet1!

The problem is is that often times the values on Sheet1! will be able to match up with as many as 12 different unique rows on Sheet2! making this incredibly difficult with only intermediate experience in VBA.  There can be duplicates that match all of the criteria. And for when this happens I would like to return the first item that matches, as long as a previous match was not made on that item.

To give you more information we have given products different values that designate where they belong based off their velocity. This has split them up into Section#, ShelvingType, Verticle, and Horizontal Location. And we are looking to match these values to the values of our previously existing locations that we have that have corresponding(matching) numbers or text values.

To go into even more detail, on sheet one we have the products with values on where they should go. One sheet two with have pre-existing locations for which products can go that have values that are represntative of that location. So, we want to take the products NEW location values off page one and match the existing location values on page two. The problem is that for every location there are up to 12products that could go there. So, we want to go in order saying that product1 goes in the first location with matched values while product2 goes in the next location with matched values, and so on and so fourth

Comment: Your question is tagged with `excel-formula` and `excel-vba`. What are you looking for?

Comment: What if you created a helper column that concatenated the four criteria and did a COUNTIF of that column, and duplicated that on the second sheet? Then do a lookup using five criteria, instead? Not the most elegant, perhaps, but should get the job done, yeah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited to remove previous responses**

Based on your further elaboration, if I understand correctly, I agree with the comment left by @Aaron Contreras. You should create helper columns which show a 'unique ID' where all criteria match, as well as an additional helper column which increases as more items of the same criteria code are found. This will become the 'ultra-unique' ID for that item.

At this point I don't think array formulas will be possible, though I will leave in the answer which provides the result of the first matching criteria *without further eliminating 'previously used' results*. This could likely be further refined, but I doubt it would be more elegant than simply using the helper columns shown in my response below. At least, I can't figure out how to do it elegantly.

**To summarize my assumptions:**

-Your available space is in sheet1; column A contaions something like the location of that available space, and columns B-E contain criteria for anything which will be stored there.
-Your new list of items to be placed in a location is in sheet2; columnA will be where our formula goes, showing the available location to put that item.

**Enter on Sheet1**
In column F on sheet1, drag down this formula:

> =B1&C1&D1&E1
>   This will create a unique ID key to be searched in the future.

However, as there will be multiple hits for the same criteria on sheet1 (because multiple locations can hold the same thing), we need to make each row 'more unique' by showing how many times that criteria combination has already occurred. This formula will thus go in column G on sheet1, starting in cell G1 and dragged down:

> =F1&countif($F$1:F1,F1)
>   As you drag it down, this will count the nth time that the specific combination of criteria has appeared on sheet1.

**Enter on Sheet2**
Create the same columns in sheet2, in columns F & G. The formulas will be exactly the same, they will just refer to sheet2 instead of sheet1.

Then the formula in column A in sheet 2, dragged down from A1, would be:

> =index(sheet1!A:A,match(G1,sheet1!G:G,0))

This will find the first time that all criteria match from sheet1, for the nth time that this criteria has been used on sheet 2.

Let me know if there is anything here I've missed.

**Unfinished array method**
Again, array responses are possible, but for your purposes likely unnecesarry; you should probably have a unique ID for all combinations anyway. However, in case you want to use the array method, you can like so (does not account for multiple locations being used; left for reference only if you want to take this up):

In sheet2, enter the following formula [confirmed with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER, every time the formula is changed] on the row 1, with the different criteria (and copied down):

> =index(Sheet1!A1:A100,match(1,(Sheet1!B1:B100=B1)*(Sheet1!C1:C100=C1)*(Sheet1!D1:D100=D1)*(Sheet1!E1:E100=E1),0))

This uses the inherent boolean logic of "TRUExTRUE = TRUE; TRUExFALSE = FALSE; FALSExFALSE = FALSE", to find the first row where there is a match of all criteria. Note that I have not made this go all the way down all columns, as with Array formulas this is a significant resource hog.

Comment: Some of the values are text and some of the values are numeric, which rules out sumifs, will the array formula still work @emwadde?

Comment: To clarify, can there be duplicates that match all of your criteria? Or will there only ever be 1 matching item that meets all criteria? If there will be multiple matches, do you want to return the first item that matches, or are you simply looking to indicate whether there is at least one item which matches all of your criteria?

Comment: Yes, there can be duplicates that match all of the criteria.  And for when this happens i would like to return the first item that matches, as long as a previous match was not made on that item.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: To give you more information we have given products different values that designate where they belong based off their velocity.  This has split them up into Section#, ShelvingType, Verticle, and Horizontal Location.  And we are looking to match these values to the values of our previously existing locations that we have that have corresponding(matching) numbers or text values.

Comment: To go a bit deeper, do you mean you essentially have a master product list in sheet1, and on sheet2 a list of specific products (with various criteria), and you want to pull the velocity from column A, for the first time that the criteria matches one of the products on the master list on sheet 1? I don't follow what you mean with "I want to return the first item that matches as long as a previous match was not made." Do you mean there might be 2 of the same 'new products' on sheet2, and you only want to display velocity the first time that product appears?

Comment: On sheet one we have the products with values on where they should go.  One sheet two with have pre-existing locations for which products can go that have values that are represntative of that location.  So, we want to take the products NEW location values off page one and match the existing location values on page two.  The problem is that for every location there are up to 12products that could go there.  So, we want to go in order saying that product1 goes in the first location with matched values while product2 goes in the next location with matched values, and so on and so fourth.

Comment: Just to flag for you @bradmahan that I have edited the response. It should now do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data starts from 2nd row (1st row for lables):

`{MATCH(A1&B1&C1&D1,B2:B100&C2:C100&D2:D100&E2:E100,0)}`

The above is an array formula, so you don't have to input the curly brackets `{`.
Simply press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` after typing the formula

[More info](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/07/12/check-multiple-criteria-with-excel-index-and-match/)